# .Net core 2.2 API versioning and proper routing

Tags: .net-core, routes, swagger, versioning, swashbuckle

I am creating an API. I use swagger but due to a huge number of controllers and actions, I want to split API endpoint by domain. To get this I thought about versioning of the API. I thought about using the Status of ApiVersion. The code of my controllers is below.

```
[ApiVersion("1.0-First")] //This is ApiVersion MajorVersion = 1, Status = "First"
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class FirstController

[ApiVersion("1.0-Second")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/other")]
public class SecondController
```

My swagger looks fine and the definitions of parts of API are good. (I know that path should be without capital letters - this is for test purposes only)

[image: Swagger screen]

But swagger can't reach any endpoint. Because the valid endpoint is at /api/v1.0-First/First not /api/v1/First.
My startUp class looks like below:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore().AddApiExplorer();
        services.AddApiVersioning(c =>
        {
            c.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
                new QueryStringApiVersionReader("V"),
                new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader());
            c.ReportApiVersions = false;
            c.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        });

        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
        {
            options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            options.SubstitutionFormat = "V";
            options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        });

        services.RegisterSwaggerConfiguration();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.AddSwagger(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>(), Configuration);
    }
```

There is some static class I wrote to add the dependencies based on IApiVersionDescriptionProvider

```
    public static class SwaggerExtension
{
    public static void RegisterSwaggerConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
    }

    public static void AddSwagger(this IApplicationBuilder app, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var prefix = "swagger";
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{prefix}/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And another class for SwaggerDoc generation.

```
    public class ConfigureSwaggerOptions : IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>
{
    private readonly IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;


    public ConfigureSwaggerOptions(IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
    {
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName, CreateInfoForApiVersion(description));
        }
    }

    private OpenApiInfo CreateInfoForApiVersion(ApiVersionDescription description)
    {
        var info = new OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Title = description.GroupName,
            Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
        };

        if (description.IsDeprecated)
        {
            info.Description += " This API version has been deprecated.";
        }

        return info;
    }
}
```

I want to get the routing work as api/v1/First or api/v1.0/First (this should not matter).
Maybe writting some custom middleware to handle this case would be good idea?
By now I am out of ideas and in general I couldn't find any articles about using status of ApiVersion.
EDIT:
Changed Title.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem some time ago. We needed to split an Api by a customer privilege/domain. The research took some time as well :), please note that we are using NSwag.

So as you already mentioned (custom middleware) we've created a custom OperationProcessor and used base type checking. Take a look at an example:

```
services.AddOpenApiDocument(document =>
        {
            document.Title = "API A";
            document.OperationProcessors.Insert(0, new IncludeAApiControllersInSwagger());
        });

services.AddOpenApiDocument(document =>
        {
            document.Title = "API B";
            document.OperationProcessors.Insert(0, new IncludeBApiControllersInSwagger());
        });
```

and then

```
private class IncludeAApiControllersInSwagger : IOperationProcessor
    {
        public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
        {
             return IsControllerInType(context, typeof(AApiController));
        }
    }

private class IncludeBApiControllersInSwagger : IOperationProcessor
    {
        public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
        {
             return IsControllerInType(context, typeof(BApiController));
        }
    }
```

The last step would be to build a proper inheritance over your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

An API version is always an API version; the values are explicit - by design. There is no universe where `1.0-First` can map to an API, but not include the status.

The status is most useful for pre-releases. For example, you might have `/first?api-version=1.0-preview.1`. When you have a volatile, preview version of an API, this prevents you from having to bump up to `1.1` and so on. `1.0` is greater than `1.0-preview.1`.

From your description, it *sounds* like you want to group or categorize your APIs by an additional level. The Swagger UI only supports a single level of grouping, but [ASP.NET API Versioning 7.0+](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer/7.0.0) now has support to make custom group names with API versions easy to configure using the [FormatGroupName](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Explorer-Options#format-group-name) option.

If your API has a custom group name like this:

```cs
[ApiVersion(1.0)]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "First")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class FirstController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() => Ok();
}
```

You can now configure the combination of both like this:

```cs
services.AddApiVersioning()
        .AddApiExplorer(
             options =>
             {
                 options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
                 options.FormatGroupName = (group, version) => $"{version}-{group}";
             });
```

This **only** works if you set a custom group name **and** define a callback. The rules are:

- Default configuration; formatted `ApiVersion`
- Group name set, but not callback; use group name
- Group name and callback set; result for callback with group and formatted `ApiVersion`
- Only callback set; ignored and uses default configuration as there's no group name

The `ApiVersion` is formatted according to `GroupNameFormat`. By default, this will simply be `ApiVersion.ToString()`. You can still use it if you want to. For example, if `GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";`, then the formatted name via the callback will result in `v1-First`.

Despite all of this configuration and grouping, the route to your API will still be: `api/v1/first`. I believe that will get you both of your goals.